# Save unpacked blender file

Tags: blend-files, file-format

I'm looking for a better way to version Blender files under Git. By default the entire file is saved as one big blob even though it is a structured format (has scenes, meshes, cameras... I can see it when linking parts of another blend file).

Because it's one binary file it doesn't play nice with version control systems. Is there a way to save an "unpacked" blend file?

I don't need features like diffing and merging, I just want the different versions stored more efficiently in the face of progress.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for a text-based alternative to the .blend format.

Comment: I'm not sure why you see this as a feature request. The question was wether this functionality exists, not a request to implement it...

Comment: By default it is not "packed" as in the textures are not packed into the actual scene data. I don't think that is what you are asking about, though . . ?

Comment: The answer is currently **no**, It's not possible to output an ascii .blend (though supposedly it wouldn't be too hard to implement this). This is [probably](http://blender.45788.x6.nabble.com/Gooseberry-VCS-td115949.html) on the [roadmap](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Development/Projects/Blender_File_Format/XML), as some [VCS work is being done as part of gooseberry](http://gooseberry.blender.org/bam-building-the-asset-manager/).

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3, looks like BlenderXML is what I'm looking, but judging by the wiki history it's dead at the moment.

Comment: .blend is binary, no matter if as a single file or multiple and thus not suitable for version control (compression on or off doesn't make much of a difference). There've been discussions about text-based formats, and BlenderXML was an attempt to implement it, but it's a dead project. A new attempt in this direction is a feature request IMO.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I agree with the OP. IMO there is a distinction between asking *how* to do something, if it's even possible, and asking *for* something to be implemented. IMO a "no" answer explaining the situation with various links etc. would be just fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need diff and merge functions, you could organize your files differently. You could create one or more scene files to be used as empty containers and link everything else.

This way you would only commit real changes in linked objects and avoid to commit lots of unchanged binary data.
You can easily switch back and forth·between your scene files to the linked ones using the [Edit Linked Library](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Edit_Linked_Library) addon.

Related:

- [Wiki Linked_Libraries](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Linked_Libraries)
- [Re-Import obj and replace existing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/re-import-obj-and-replace-existing/10715#10715)
- [diff and version manage blender work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7378/diff-and-version-manage-blender-work/7489#7489)
- [Moving a Linked Library](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13800/moving-a-linked-library)